# Getting Null value in liferay custom field?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, custom-attribute

I am using Liferay 6.1 CE version. I added my custom attribute in User entity from control panel. I want to add this my custom field in create_account.jsp hook page. I added like this way.

```
<div class="exp-ctrl-holder">
<liferay-ui:custom-attribute className="<%=User.class.getName()%>"
classPK="<%=0%>" editable="<%=true%>" label="<%=true%>"
name="user-default-group-name" />
```

After that i am trying to getting this value in UserLocalService hook class which extends UserLocalServiceWrapper class - (hook). I find each value from this but can not able to get my custom field value.

I am trying to get custom field value like this.

```
String defaultGroup = (String) User.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("defaultGroupName");
log.info("Default Group Name :" + defaultGroup);
```

But I am getting null value or default value which I set at the time of adding custom attribute. I can not find my entered value from jsp page.

Please help me.

Regards :
Pradip Bhatt
pradip.bhatt@aspiresoftware.in

Comment: First of all check that your custom field value getting saved to db? You dont have to write any logic for save custom-field, Liferay API will take care of saving it. You just have to specify custom-field tag inside form of create accound screen.. HTH

Comment: I solved it.. it is my mistake. I added custom attribute in jsp file outside form tag.. Stupid mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to write any logic for save custom-field, Liferay API will take care of saving it.

You just have to specify custom-field tag inside form of create account screen.

Hope this would help.